# number of ordered pairs and sets

Tags: combinatorics

I got 2 questions(truth or false with explanation) which I found confusing a bit and I would like to know what the different approach should be and if my approach is right .
**we are working with the set A={1,2,3,4,5,6}**
the first question is **the number of sets {B,C} that B,C⊆A , $|B|$=$|C|$=$3$ and $B∩C=∅$ is equal to the number of words that their length is $6$ and each of the digits $0,1$ shows $3$ times in it**

My way was that I looked at the set **{1,2,3,4,5,6}** and i took **{1,2,3} for A and {4,5,6} for B** which are different so we got for the first option  ${6 \choose 3}$ which is 20 and for the second we got  ${3 \choose 3}$ which is 1 , so total its equal to 20. as for the words we got 3 times '1' and 3 times '0' so total 6  and 3 of each so we got $\left(\frac{6!}{3!*3!}\right)$ which is also 20 so the first one is true but the second question is

**the number of *ordered pairs* $<B,C>$ that $B,C⊆A$ , $|B|$= $2$ $|C|$=$3$ and  $B∩C=∅$ is equal to the number of words that their length is 6 and each of the digits are shown $0$ one time , $1$ two time , $2$ three times**

The thing that got me confused the most here is when they said ordered pairs. So I know that for the number (0,1,2) it will be ${6 \choose 1}$ * ${5 \choose 2}$ * ${3 \choose 3}$ which is 60 and for B,C it would be ${6 \choose 2}$ * ${4 \choose 3}$  also = $60$

My question is , is it right to do that? Is there really no difference in solving just normal sets or ordered pairs? Because i did it in the same way but it feels wrong as then why would they state that they are ordered sets .

Thanks for any type of help , and I am sorry if there are some translation mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first question you can think of a word of lenght 6 in witch 0 and 1 appears 3 times in this way: given such a word (for example 001011) you can take the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and put in the set $B$ all the numbers that correspond to the position of a $0$ in the word (in this case $1,2,4$) and in the set $A$ all the numbers that correspond to the position of a $1$ in the word (in this case $3,5,6$).
Viceversa, given such a couple of sets you can construct a word representing that partition  in the same way: the first digit is a $0$ if $1 \in B$ and is a $1$ if $1 \in B$ and so on with the other digits.

In the second question you can apply the same method of the first answer by creating a new set $D$ such that, all the numbers who are not in $B$ or $C$ are in $D$. In this way, given $B$ and $C$, you can create $D$ and then a word in the same way putting a $0$ for elements in $D$ , a $1$ for elements in $C$ and a $2$ for elments in $B$. Viceversa, also in this case, you can construct a word representing that partition in the same way:  the first digit is a $0$ if $1 \in D$, is a $1$ if $1 \in C$ and is a $2$ if $1 \in B$ and so on with the other digits.

P.S. There is no difference in the second question between ordered pairs and not ordered one becaus you can distinguish the two sets just by looking at their cradinality.